# Trying to explain grammatical error in fragmented compound sentence

Tags: verbs, verb-agreement, lists, compound-subjects

> It was a turning point that led us to discover the unique opportunity to apply the technology to aerospace, and the company rebranded as *****.

Could somebody possibly help me explain what is wrong with this sentence? (Verbs not agreeing? Subjects not agreeing?) I'm trying to help a colleague but tired brain not articulate enough today.

Comment: It sounds clunky, but I'm not sure there's a grammatical error. The part after "and" is a separate clause, it doesn't have to agree.

Comment: If _you_ discovered an opportunity to apply 'the technology' to aerospace, how can you be sure others (or you yourselves) won't discover another opportunity to apply the technology to aerospace?  The 'unique' claim seems strong. // It was a turning point that led us to discover this opportunity (so far not mirrored) to apply the technology to aerospace .... //  It was a turning point that led us to discover this opportunity (by its very nature not duplicatable) to apply the technology to aerospace .... But this isn't a matter of grammar.

Comment: Strangely, although there is only one "unique opportunity" I would say "discover **a** unique opportunity" rather than "discover **the** unique opportunity", because there are many opportunities.

Comment: I have a feeling that what OP really wants to say is that their discovery was a turning point:  “Our discovery of a unique opportunity to apply the technology to aerospace was a turning point for the company that led to its rebranding as ****”

Comment: The simplest correction would be to use a parallel construction: unique opportunity to apply the technology to aerospace and rebrand the company as ....

Comment: Turn, turn, turn. What’s the point?

Answer (score 5):

I would not call the sentence grammatically incorrect, but it is clunky.

One issue is that the sentence doesn't make clear the relationship between *us* (the agent that discovered a unique opportunity) and *the company* (the agent that rebranded). If the two are equivalent, when the sentence switches from first person plural to third person, a reader has to fill in more context to understand the causality (see ["Avoiding shifts," 4. Person](https://webapps.towson.edu/ows/shifts.htm)). Consistent first-person would help in that case:

> It was a turning point that led **[us]** to discover the unique opportunity to apply the technology to aerospace, and **[we/our company]** rebranded as *****.

Another issue is the it-cleft sentence construction: "It was NP that VP" rather than "NP VP." (See [Cleft sentences, English Grammar Today](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/cleft-sentences-it-was-in-june-we-got-married)) These are grammatically fine in speech but can be clunky in writing. Removing the excess words yields:

> A turning point led us to discover the unique opportunity to apply the technology to aerospace, and our company rebranded as *****.

Finally, the sentence has an issue with jargon or buzzwords. *Turning point*. *Unique opportunity*. Rhetorician Richard Lanham developed [the Paramedic Method](https://owl.purdue.edu/owl/subject_specific_writing/writing_in_engineering/indot_workshop_resources_for_engineers/documents/20080306044511_727.pdf) (originally in the book *[Revising Prose](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Revising_Prose/KR-FPwAACAAJ?hl=en)*) to defray sentences like this. His method would particularly highlight nominalizations (adjectives or verbs turned to nouns) like *turning point*, unnecessary words or phrases, as well as the aforementioned it-cleft. Since the Paramedic Method is open-ended, there are multiple ways to revise the sentence; here's my attempt:

> We discovered we could apply our current technology to aerospace and rebranded our company as *****.

Comment: Much better answer than mine...+1

Comment: Edited & back to be able to alter downvote. All helpful points, and it-clefting mentioned. Apologies.